# Probability of one candidate passing the test.

Tags: probability, expectation

There is a class of many students and viva is going on for them. For each student the time taken for viva is given and the probability that he will pass is given.If one student fails the examiner wills stop conducting the viva. If we have both these what is the minimum expected time that we can understand at least one has failed or all have passed the viva. That is expected time at which viva will be finished.

Comment: So what have you got so far? Do you have a sum or some other expression for the expected time?

Comment: I don't have any idea of how to solve this. you could atleast point me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in a concrete case with three students ordered with probabilities of passing of $p_1 = 0.1, p_2 = 0.5$ and $p_3 = 0.2$ together with times of $T_1 = 3$, $T_2  = 7$ and $T_3 = 9$, then the expected total time by similar logic is

$$E[t] = Pr(\text{ Student #1 fails })T_1 + Pr(\text{ Student #1 passes but #2 fails })(T_1 + T_2) $$ $$+ Pr(\text{ Students #1 and #2 pass })(T_1 + T_2 + T_3) $$ $$   = (1-p_1)T_1 + p_1(1-p_2)(T_1 + T_2) + p_1p_2(T_1 + T_2 + T_3)$$
$$ = \ ...$$

Comment: In example give with times t=3,7,9 and prob 0.1,0.5,0.2 the expected time was 4.04. Your equation seems to cross that value.

Comment: Oh, you're saying you have probabilities $p_j$ (not the same thing as $P_j$) and $T_j$ for each student. I've added something above for that case. See if it makes sense.

Comment: Could you please give me an example.

Comment: See above for the logic in your situation

Comment: substituting I got 4.15but solution is 4.04

Comment: I agree with the calculation. But the logic is sound. So unless there's something else going on, the logic remains sound and 4.04 is an incorrect answer.

Comment: I will try to solve it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @snepp, if you decided to cheat on the contest (https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/quora-haqathon/challenges/schedule) by asking ridiculously perverted questions on StackExchange, at least try to derive the last bit from the Simon's excellent answer and get that the order of your tests is not limited to exactly 3, 7, 9. Put them as 3, 9, 7 and you'll have your desired 4.04 = 0.9*3+0.1*0.8*12+0.1*0.2*19.

Comment: Oh, that's what this is. And I see now why we weren't getting exactly 4.04; because the the 7 and 9 were given in the wrong order. Thanks @shoumikhin.

Comment: Btw, you can also look from this perspective:

Time = T1 + T2 * (probability the first one did not fail) + T3 * (probability the first two did not fail) + and so on.

So we get:

Time = T1 + T2*P1 + T3*P1*P2 + ... + Tn*P1*...*Pn-1.

To minimize it you either go with N! permutations (good luck) or sit a while and discover an interesting property of each Ti over Pi and how they influence the final sum (I won't tell more to keep you intrigued).